# how can i start understanding the source code of GNU-linker

Tags: c, linux, linker, gnu, ld

Iam an engineer working with GNU tools for over an year,
Iam fairly good at using almost all the gnu-tools (readelf, gcc, gdb, nm objcopy, objdump ..), and very strongly biased towards C language.

I started reading John R Levine's Linkers&Loaders.
So far so good but i always wanted to understand deeply how linker does what it does.

so i choose to understand the linker source code x64_64 architecture, i have downloaded source of gnu-binutils but i am unable to understand where to start, so if somebody can give me a head's up or kickstart i will start reading the code.

please do explain the source code of gnulinker at very base level and point me to right direction.

I have also worked on a project where i got to edit few linker scripts, so i am good with linker scripts (GNU) at basic level

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, sorry but StackOverflow is really not intended for this kind of very broad question. There is a C_Programming subreddit which I think is not limited in scope the way StackOverflow is. It is possible you may get advice there: https://www.reddit.com/r/C_Programming/

Comment: Though this question is marked as `too broad`, I believe that the low-level coders community will dramatically benefit from an answer to this question.

Comment: i understand the question is too broad, but so is the code for GNUlinker :D, i am not able to understand where to start, just a little information as where to start for x86_64 would help me BIG